# Can't install time module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried `pip install time` and `sudo -H pip install time`, but I keep getting the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for time

I'm working in PyCharm, but what really doesn't make sense is that I can import time in the Python Console but not in my actual code.

Comment: time is a builtin module

Comment: Did you happen to name a file `time.py` (or a folder containing Python modules `time`)? If it's in your working directory, it will shadow the built-in `time` module.

Answer (score 34):

The [`time` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) is part of Python's standard library.  It's installed along with the rest of Python, and you don't need to (nor can you!) install it with `pip`.

> I can import time in the Python Console

Yes, because it's already installed.

> but not in my actual code

I don't believe you.  Show us the exact error message you get when you try.

Comment: Happening to me, too: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8axqrcafq924fi5/Screenshot%202018-01-15%2015.49.07.png?dl=0

Comment: Answer from snibbets was more helpful. Just add `import time` at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a PyCharm bug. I am using the time module with PyCharm and it complains that 'time' is an unresolved reference, even when I use

```
import time
```

at the beginning of my file. However, there is no run-time error when I execute my program, even though PyCharm does not recognise `time` as a valid module.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `time.sleep(secs)` that should work fine.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: Well, he is trying to use `time()` but getting an error and thinking that he might need to install the *time module*, for that reason I suggested `time.sleep()` instead (been there, done that)

Answer (score 1):

just use it . `time library default installed` in python
for use : add to code :

```
import time
```

and use for example :

```
time.sleep(20) #20 second
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an object with the name "time" because it will conflict with the "time" module.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already imported time up top `import time`
and time is shown as an unresolved reference, then probably either an existing variable of time exists or time is imported outside of the function -- in both cases, you should be able to call time with a different name.

```py
import time as tme

def_hi():
    print(tme.time())
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if import time is in grey, it works ! You just gotta put `time.init()` or something like that right after it

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the error, while referring the time on the 'requirements.txt' and pushing app to cloud foundry.

So the errors is expected. So, its possible on other scenarios also.
I just removed the time from the 'requirements.txt' before push my app to make it work.!

Answer (score 0):

time is pre-installed because when I import time "import time" 
everything goes well

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem, I think it's because one variable was called time...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this bug too with pycharm. If I import time outside of the function then I won't be able to call it inside the function.

```
import time
def poop():
    print(time.time()) # Undefined varr time
```

I was able to get around it by importing as a different name

```
import time as tm
def poop():
    print(tm.time()) # Works
```

If you want to be inefficient you could do

```
def poop():
    import time
    print(time.time()) # Works
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, the only thing that happened to me was that a variable was given the name "time", that's why the time module didn't work, I didn't know this, so after searching, I was able to change the name of that variable and To end the torment I was trapped in.

Answer (score -1):

You should first import the library. So add a statement like:
import

Comment: The question is asking about installing a module from pip, not importing it into a script.