# I'm trying to figure out how to install this lib on python (time)

Tags: python, python-3.6

im new to python and i was trying to install "time" library on python, i typed
pip install time
but the compiler said this

`C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6>pip install time ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for time`

i dont know how to resolve, can anyone help me? please be the more simple u can cause im not too good in py, as i said im new, thx to everyone!

P.S.
the py version is 3.6

thx everyone, im stupid xd

Comment: Try this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522650/cant-install-time-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522650/cant-install-time-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is part of the default preinstalled libraries so you shouldn't have to install it.
just use:

```
import time
```

Answer (score 1):

Time is a module that comes built-in with python so no need to install anything, just import it :

`import time`

Answer (score 1):

This should already be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522650/cant-install-time-module).

Since time is part of Pythons standard library you neither need to nor can you install it via pip.