# Getting an error message while trying to install pandas packages using pip3 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, package

My code starts with installing these packages -

```
    pip3 install ipython 
    pip3 install selenium  
    pip3 install time 
    pip3 install parsel
    pip3 install csv
```

**but I get -**

```
File "<ipython-input-7-cae965d78112>", line 1
    conda install ipython
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried replacing **pip3** with  **pip** and **conda**, it still gives the same error.Please help me to install these packages.

thanks!!!

Comment: You should write these commands as shell commands, not within an iPython notebook.

Comment: @zabop you mean to write them in Anaconda prompt?

Comment: If you are on Windows then yes I guess, but I'm not that familiar with Anaconda/Windows.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try: colab.research.google.com

Comment: ```
    pip3 install csv

    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time

    ERROR: No matching distribution found for time
```
i got this

Comment: use the online python environment then, I recommend.

Comment: @zabop, is there any way to install the packages in my pc, I wouldn't prefer using online editors.

Comment: Your error is the same as this person's error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522650/cant-install-time-module/46658551, maybe look at that thread.

Answer (score 0):

[`pip3`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/quickstart/) and [`conda`](https://conda.io/en/latest/index.html) are utilities separate to the Python programming language. `pip3` and `conda` make it easier for users to install python packages to their machine/virtual environment which is why you get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` because what you've written is not valid Python.

If you want to use `pip3` or `conda` these commands should be used at into a terminal. These tools search online for modules you want to install, download them and install them into the appropriate location (for your user or into your virtual enviroment). If you try to install something that can't be found online in the [pypi](https://pypi.org/) you'll get an error.

You've tried to install the module `csv` using `pip3 install csv`. The `csv` module is part of Python's standard library so `pip3` will not find this package on pypi. Being part of the standard library means that every installation of Python has this library. To use the `csv` module you can do `import csv` in your notebook/`.py` file. The same goes for the module `time`.